# How to resurrect an AWS cluster using command line tools that I cannot ssh into?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

About two weeks ago I was suddenly unable to `ssh` into my AWS machines, they just time out.  Really, the best information I can get from an `ssh -vvv <ip>` is `ssh: connect to host <ip> port 22: Connection refused`.  if the ip address has changed no one told me about it.

Since I still have the information about the machines from when I set them up, I'm wondering if there's a way to resurrect an AWS cluster using command line tools.

Here is all of the information I have about the machines in the cluster:

```
- instance IDs
- region
- groupName
- VpcId
- SubnetId
- SubnetId
- public IP addresses
```

Using the AWS CLI, is there a way to resurrect these instances?

*EDIT* I'm pretty sure the instances are `stopped`, judging by this:  When I do `aws describe-instances --region <region> --instance-ids <id>` I see `"State" { "Code": 80, "Name": "stopped"}`.

Comment: Is it possible that your IP address changed and you had a security group enabling ssh access only to your old IP address?

Comment: When Ben said is my best guess too, it's your security group or NACL. Open up SSH on 0.0.0.0/0 temporarily and see if you can ssh in. If you can then work out your IP and narrow the range down to a /32.

Comment: I am not sure about that BenForce and @Tim.  I am really new at this, how do I "Open up SSH on 0.0.0.0/0"?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html you need to learn how to use AWS or hire someone, this is a real basic

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. Connection refused is not a timeout. And that does make a difference to what are the possible explanations.

Comment: Your edit says the instances are stopped. Have you considered starting them?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use [reboot-instances](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=aws%20cli%20reboot%20instance). (Assuming you imply, by the use of "resurrect", that they're in a down state and need a reboot. If you mean to imply something other than that, be more specific.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the instances are `stopped`, judging by this:  When I do `aws describe-instances --region <region> --instance-ids <id>` I see `"State" { "Code": 80, "Name": "stopped"}`.  I think that means they are still able to be resurrected right?

Answer (score 0):

The command should be:
`aws ec2 reboot-instances --region $REGION --instance-ids $INSTANCE_ID`
And replace $REGION and $INSTANCE_ID with the correct information. You will need to have valid session keys for this command to work.

If your instances were in the "Stopped" state (or shut down), they'll lose their public IP addresses (unless they had an Elastic IP attached), so you'll have to run:
`aws ec2 describe-instances --region $REGION`
to get a status on all the instances you have permissions to view, and find out their new public IP addresses.

Reference from the AWS CLI Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/reboot-instances.html

Comment: I can't vote yet. +1 though

Comment: I have the correct boto creds, so I should be fine there.  I'll try rebooting the instances to see if they can be recovered.  HOWEVER, are you sure that the instance id won't change when they get rebooted???

Comment: Instance-id will not change on reboot. They will persist until the instance is terminated (which is AWS's term for deleted). Also, the private IP will persist as well, you only really have to worry about the public IP changing, and even that will persist if you issue the reboot command on a running instance. However, if the instance is "Stopped" (AWS's term for "shut down"), the public IP is released and you can't get it back, you'll just get another random public IP when you start it up again.